# Gradle : set sourceCompatibility with different value for test

Tags: gradle

I would like to compile the code with java 7, but test the code with java 8.

How I can declare differents values for sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility ?

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently an easy way to have one and the same Gradle build compile and test code with different JDKs. (You'd have to provide the path to a JDK installation directory.) A good option is to run Gradle (and therefore compile code and run tests) with JDK 8, but set source compatibility to 1.7. The only problem that this will not guard against is incidentally using JDK 8 APIs. There are various ways to solve this problem, one of which is to have a CI build that runs Gradle with JDK 7.